# ConstraintLayout make cell items fit screen viewport

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-view, android-constraintlayout

I am trying to create a screen which should look like this

[image]

But when I create the view using the XML code as per below

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/fb_constraintLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="me.buddy.buddy.ui.BenefitsActivity$BenefitsFragment">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/fb_animals"
        android:src="@drawable/animal_love"

        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/fb_meal_data"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/fb_environment"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/fb_meal_data"
        android:src="@drawable/food"

        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/fb_animals"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/fb_health"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/fb_environment"
        android:src="@drawable/environment"

        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/fb_animals"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/fb_health"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/fb_hunger"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/fb_health"
        android:src="@drawable/health"

        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/fb_meal_data"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/fb_section_label"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/fb_environment"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/fb_hunger"
        android:src="@drawable/bowl"

        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/fb_environment"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/fb_section_label"/>



    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/fb_section_label"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"


        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/fb_health"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/fb_hunger"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I am getting a screen like below in my app

[image]

Do note that this layout is inside a fragment of an activity as depicted in the tools tag in the xml. Hence the additional floating action button and the back arrow in the actual layout.

However what I am not able to understand is why is icon of the food bowl getting pushed below the visible screen space in the actual layout.

Any resolution to this issue? I would like to avoid using Scrollview as much as possible.

For reference, XML Code of parent activity is attached below

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="me.buddy.buddy.ui.BenefitsActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/ab_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/ab_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:title="@string/app_name">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/ab_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/ab_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Java code for adding fragment to main activity as per below:

First the parent class:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_benefits);
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.ab_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.ab_container);
mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
```

Then inside Fragment class:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_benefits_dashboard, container, false);
return rootView;}
```

Comment: Can you share the layout XML of parent activity?

Comment: Your vertical chains look OK, so it seems that the bowl shouldn't slip so low but it is. Can you share the XML for the `CoordinatorLayout` and any code you may use to manipulate the layout?

Comment: What version of `ConstraintLayout` are you using?

Comment: @Cheticamp - I am using 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'. Also added parent activity xml

Comment: @SouravBagchi - added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are trying to solve is easily accomplished using `ConstraintLayout` [`Guideline`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/Guideline.html)s.

You just define 2 horizontal guidelines: one at 33%, the other one at 66%.
Then all you have to do, is to position your views relative to these guidelines.

Here's a skeleton implementation of your screen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#53d94f"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/view2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#d9c74f"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/view1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#4f68d9"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/view4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/guideline" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#d95a4f"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/view3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/guideline" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#4fd4d9"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/view6"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline2" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view6"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#c94fd9"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/view5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guideline2" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.33" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.66" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here's the output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I defined the guidelines in my code and arranged all my imageviews wrt those.But the issue persists. I have tried on 2 different real phones - HTC and Samsung. And same problem in both. I have added the parent activity code as well in my question now. Do you think there is some issues there?

Comment: Can you show the place, where you add **this** view into view hierarchy?

Comment: It's a fragment. So I add it in the code. First I create the parentview. Code added above

Comment: Can you post a simple project with that behavior in github?

Comment: Apply `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to `ViewPager`.

Comment: I removed the line app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" from my ToolBar and all of a sudden it started to render perfectly....  Once again thank you for all your effort and help. Much appreciated...

Answer (score 2):

The `Toolbar` in your Main Activity pushes down the ViewPager. The `AppBarLayout` is mainly used in a Tabbed Layout for using a `TabLayout`. If you are using a `TabLayout` inside the `AppBarLayout`, the `Toolbar` will hide automatically after launching the activity and your `ViewPager` will occupy the full window.

**The Solution:**
Remove the whole `AppBarLayout` with `Toolbar` from your Activity and also remove the `NoActionBar` theme from Activity manifest

Or, don't use `CoordinatorLayout` for your parent activity.